# Socket.io object with no data sent in the first go[setInterval]

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, websocket, socket.io

Ok, so I have a NodeJS app that I am creating.
It involves sending a HTTP request to an API, which returns JSON data, which I want to display to the client in real time using socket.io
I'm using setInterval() to run the function very 'x' seconds.

I was hoping to declare a global variable and then call the function when the connection is established(socket.io) and then use setInterval() but it doesnt seem to work out.

The problem:
It displays undefined data for the first 'x' seconds.
Heres my code(I am removing the unnecessary part)

```
var globalObject = {}
function APICall () {
request.get(APIUrl, function (error, response, body) {
globalObject = JSON.parse(body)
 })}
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
APICall()
socket.emit('newdata', globalObject)
}

setInterval(function () {
request.get(bitstampAPI, function (error, response, body) {
    bitstamp = JSON.parse(body)
    socket.emit('price', bitstamp)
    })
  }, 10000)
})
```

P.S: Ignore the braces and parenthesis errors, I removed some of the unnecessary logic from my app so there might be some issue in there.

Bottom line: for the first 10 seconds, socket.io emits an object with no data in it, after that, the setInterval() kicks in and sends in the data from the API

Comment: You will need to do an initial request to `bitstampAPI` to get the data first since `setInterval` will not make the first request until 10 seconds have passed

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here you emit `'newdata'` as soon as you get a connection, but **before** you got a response from `APIUrl`.

You should change your `APICall` function to return a promise or to receive a callback, then you can emit `'newdata'` after you actually updated `globalObject`.

Something like this (callback):

```
var globalObject = {};
function APICall(callback) {
  request.get(APIUrl, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      // handle error
    } else {
      var data = JSON.parse(body);
      globalObject = data;
      callback(data);
    }
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  APICall(function(data) {
    socket.emit('newdata', data)
  });
});
```

or this (promise):

```
var globalObject = {};
function APICall() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request.get(APIUrl, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        globalObject = data;
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  APICall().then(function (data) {
    socket.emit('newdata', data)
  });
});
```

P.S as you can see, I wouldn't use a global variable at all (and handle errors).